# Div container with image and other divs next to each other

Tags: html, css, css-float, alignment, stylesheet

I'm trying to draw a container which would contain an image (thumbnail) on the left side and a few divs next to the image (vertically: in the middle of the container). They would contain buttons and drop-down lists and, possibly, something else, apart from the plain text.

I know I need to use `float:left` and so on, but no luck for me — doesn't look any good. So I won't even provide an example of what I've achieved. Instead, I will provide my vision:

[image: vision of the problem]

I *don't* want a table solution, only divs — if it is possible, of course.

Could somebody help we with this one?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.  We aren't here to do your work for you, we are here to help with problem code.

Comment: This is not a vague question, it was exactly the question I had. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;`. It's basically a hybrid of inline and block behavior. Here's  a sample, HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
    <img src = "pic.png" class = "inbl"/>
    <div class = "inbl"></div>
    <div class = "inbl"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inbl {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.container {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

And a little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/PzSUX/).

Comment: So, If I understand correctly, with inline-block'ing you don't need any floats ?

Comment: @Dmitri Yep, you don't need any floats at all -- see the demo if you'd like.

Comment: I've seen the demo, and the result is very good! Thank you very much. Very good, clean and simple solution.

Comment: I dont know if you can still read this: Your solution works, but, I wanted to know, how could I use floats. I wanted to have an image to the left, and **div2** (see picture) to the right, and that DIV to be vertically-aligned to the middle. Could you help me with that ?

Comment: @Dmitri Did you try changing the `vertical-align: top`; in the CSS to `middle`?

Comment: I did. In fact, once you apply any of the floats, vertical-align no longer works. You could try it yourself.

Comment: @Dmitri Oh, well why are you `floating` in the first place? If your goal is to center the middle `div` (div1), it can be done without floating.

Comment: Not anymore. But, actually, nevermind. I have solved my problem using <table>,<tr>, <td>. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 4):

you can create the table view using the div tag also. like this way

```
<div style="display:table">
    <div style="display:table-cell">
       <img src="src" style="width:150px;height:100px;/>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;" align="center">
       <div> your container1 </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle" align="center">
        <div> your container2 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's wrong in this solution?

Comment: Well, to start with, it's not me who downvoted your answer. I think it might have to do with the following: you used inline styles, which is generically non-preferable, you used the `align` attribute, which is deprecated, and it's a bit more complex than using `display: inline-block;`. Again, it's not me who downvoted your answer, I think it's conceptually valid.

Comment: @Abody97 I am not blame on you but a negative voter should give some comment so atleast we know what the wrong in my answer anyway I have also learn from this, actually m rare user of html and css.

Comment: Thank you for the solution provided. I don't know who downvoted, but it wasn't me! Thank you once again!